# Search box has white font color, using IE8

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, search

The search boxes on both [gaming] and [gaming.meta] appear to have white font color. Can't see what I'm typing:

[image]

Selected:

[image]

Doesn't happen on other SE websites.

Comment: In firefox, the searchbar itself is blue (or gray), so the white text shows up fine. I think the issue here is the search box itself, not the text. Still a bug though, good catch!

Comment: The text is *supposed* to be white, the background is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search box didn't have a fallback background color for browsers that don't support RGBA (i.e. semi-transparent) colors; IE8 is the last such browser that we still support.

This is fixed in the next build of the site.